# Leading 0 removed from argument in Powershell

Tags: powershell

New to Powershell, never needed it before I started this job. I'm just making an easier way for me to keep our stores pinging and kill some time learning. Some pretext; Our stores are always 4 numbers, so 1096 is 1096 but 704 is 0704.

Here is my current script:

```
$args.Length;
foreach ($arg in $args) {
Test-Connection $arg'router' }

Write-Host 'Pinging Store #'$arg

if($arg.legnth -lt 4) {
($arg).insert(0,'0') 
}
```

If I execute with the argument ***1096*** all is well in the world, but if I use ***0704*** the leading 0 disappears. I've tried a number of potential resolutions, but I've found most are trying to remove trailing zeroes so I've just been trying to reverse engineer their solutions. What is the best way to ensure that the leading 0 isn't removed so the host is able to be found.

**0704router** exists.

**704router** doesn't exist.

Comment: PowerShell is converting your argument to an integer, where `704` and `0704` are equivalent. `$arg.ToString("0000")`

Comment: Where are the store numbers coming from? How are you getting them into your script?

Comment: Can you show us the content of $args? It looks like PowerShell is using its value as an integer. So let PowerShell know that you want to use it as a string.

Comment: That makes sense. I've updated my question to add a few lines that make things a bit more clear. $arg is 0704 being converted to 704 because as you guys have said, its being treated as an integer. One second, going to convert to string.

Comment: Why use `$args` when you can use a named parameter and specify its type?

Comment: This is my first 20 minutes in Powershell which is why I'm just using $arg as opposed to proper ways.

Comment: For the users voting to close this/downvoting, please by all means let me know why. If this question can be improved, tell me. Nothing productive comes from shadow flagging. :)

Comment: Please don't edit solutions into your question. If you have solved the problem, you should post the solution below as an answer, so you can accept the answer and mark this question "solved".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue of how you *call* the script. You may be doing something like this:

```
./MyScript.ps1 1096 0704
```

Which will give you 2 arguments, but since they are unquoted and contain only digits, they are interpreted as integers, and so you lose leading zeros.

Instead, tell PowerShell you want these as string values by quoting them:

```
./MyScript.ps1 '1096' '0704'
```

Comment: Well in most cases there will be only 1 argument, but this answer does help a lot with context on how I should convert the integer to a string by default. I don't want to have to manually enter the ' ' each time, and every example of ```ToString()``` I'm finding is very convoluted. Would you be able to give a brief example of how to tell all arguments to become strings?

Comment: @CodeSpent if you're using `$args`, then this is the way to do that; you'll have to make them strings on calling. If you want to use full parameters, you can cast them as `[string]` in the parameter definition, but this will also change the rest of your code that refers to the parameters.

Comment: Are you saying in the state of my current script, it is not possible to convert the argument to a string?

Comment: @CodeSpent I'm saying in its current state it's not possible to force an argument to be interpreted as a string before it gets interpreted as an integer. Since you know the format of your store numbers, you could convert them after the fact and pad with zeros: `"$arg".PadLeft(4, '0')`

Comment: @CodeSpent hm, that's.. surprising. But if you have more than one argument it will make a single string out of all of them. `$stores  = [string[]]$args` should make an array where each arg is a string, which you can then use `foreach` to iterate over.

Comment: Ah fair point. I'll go ahead and mark this resolved, though, because ultimately the solution was making the argument a string rather than an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The `[string]$Args[1]` worked for me and 
it seems like the behavior is changing from version to version - same script worked without conversion with `PS 2.0`

Hope this helps!